# Ruby Implementation of RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm

Tags: ruby, md5, rsa

Does anybody know of ruby implementation of RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm defined at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321

I found a javascript implementation at [https://developer.openx.org/fisheye/browse/openads/branches/2.0/branches/openads-2.0.11/admin/md5.js?r=16584](http://developer.openx.org/fisheye/browse/openads/branches/2.0/branches/openads-2.0.11/admin/md5.js?r=16584) ... It has a function MD5 which does the encoding. Anything similar on ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's plenty of them [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=ruby+md5&btnG=Search)

In fact, you're likely to find one using:

```
require 'digest/md5'
```

Comment: I checked it out, it doesn't seem to have this particular algorithm.

Comment: It very likely _does_ have the bog-standard MD5 algorithm.  What do you mean?

Comment: The algorithm is below (pasted from javascript code) function MD5(entree) ...  for (i=0;i<4;i++) ka+=shl(digestBits[15-i], (i*8)); 
for (i=4;i<8;i++) kb+=shl(digestBits[15-i], ((i-4)*8)); ...
s=hexa(kd)+hexa(kc)+hexa(kb)+hexa(ka); 
return s; 
digest/md5 does only md5 encoding. This is more complex.

Comment: That extra stuff you've found is just hex-encoding the 128-bit result of the MD5 digest.  The real MD5 algorithm is found in the stuff I posted.

Comment: and BTW, that code at openx.org is broken - it's only good for 7-bit ASCII, so if your text contains byte values < 32 || > 127 it'll produce non-conformant digests.